# Formulas don't work when copied using Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formula, copy-paste

I made this script that basically copies the table in the first sheet and pastes it in the second one exactly 3 rows after the last one. The problem is that everything works but when I paste the formulas in the targeted cells of the F column the cells show the error "#NAME?". This is particularly weird since if I copy the content of that cell and paste it somewhere else it works fine. Why? What can I do to resolve this problem?
Here' the code:

```
function inserisciDatabase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];
  
  var startRow = destination.getLastRow()+3;

  var numRows = destination.getLastRow()+16;

  var sourceRange = source.getRange("A6:K18");

  sourceRange.copyFormatToRange(destination, 1, 11, startRow, numRows);

  sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 11, startRow, numRows);

  //var sourcePresenteRange = source.getRange("F6:F18");
  //var formulas = sourcePresenteRange.getFormulas();

  var b = 0;

  for(a = startRow; a < numRows; ++a){
    var cell = destination.getRange(a,4);
    var cellVal = cell.getValue();
    if(cellVal === true){
      cell.insertCheckboxes();
      cell.check();
    }
    else if(cellVal === false){
      cell.insertCheckboxes();
    }

    var formulaRange = destination.getRange(a,6);
    var formula = '=SE(VAL.VUOTO(E'+a+');"";SE(OGGI()>=DATA.MESE(E'+a+';-1);"SCADENZA";"REGOLARE"))'
    formulaRange.setValue(formula);
    b = b + 1;
  }

  var rangeSollecitato = destination.getRange(startRow, 7, 13, 1);
  rangeSollecitato.insertCheckboxes();
}
```

Here the sheets

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Gianmarco.

- If I copy the content of that cell and paste it somewhere else the formula works just fine.
- Refreshing the page doesnt't do anything
- Using "setValue" instead of "setFormula" changes nothing.

Thank you so much in advance.

Gianmarco.

Comment: 1. Try a simple formula `=Sum(2)` 2. Try English formulas

Comment: It appears that you are experiencing the same issue as described in this [post](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/157875544?hl=en&msgid=158014583). As stated in that post *"the problem is with how Google Sheets reacts to formulas the Apps Script creates"*. It would also be beneficial if you could submit this to the [Google Issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) tracker to verify if this is intended Or if there is a possible issue between Apps Script & Google Sheets. AFAIK, there's no official documentation regarding this matter.